# Why is this not a retain cycle if self is referred to within a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks

```
@interface myViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, copy)  NSString* (^translateKey)(NSString *);
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *aString;
@end
```

**case#1**

```
@implementation
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    _translateKey = ^NSString*(NSString* translationKey){
        return _aString;
    };
}
@end
```

- The compiler complains about #1 being retain cycle. And This I understand

**case#2**

```
@implementation
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString * (^translationKeyBlock)(NSString *) = ^NSString*(NSString* translationKey){        
        return _aString;
    };
    _translateKey = translationKeyBlock;
}
```

- The compiler does not complain about case#2. But this is still a retain cycle right?

Comment: is `_translateKey = translationKeyBlock;` meant to be inside the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: What's `_currentTag`? Are these two `@implementations` for `myViewController`?

Comment: i have fixed the 2 errors in the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 2 still a cycle? Yes

Why is it missed? The compiler's flow analysis doesn't catch the case, which is a bit surprising in this case (the optimiser can surely elide `translationKeyBlock` reducing case 2 to case 1).

What should you do? Submit it to Apple as an "enhancement request", or just plain "bug" via bugreporter.apple.com. They might come back with a good reason they don't catch it, or they might support it in future. (It's not the first flow analysis issue I've seen.)

Answer (score 1):

I presume your question is:

```
@implementation
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString * (^translationKeyBlock)(NSString *) = ^NSString*(NSString* translationKey){        
        return _aString;
    };
    _translateKey = translationKeyBlock;
}
```

It's still a retain cycle, but compiler will complain nothing.

if you set block to _translateKey Directly, compiler will find this line will make a retain cycle and throw a error or warning. 
However, compiler will not sure if you set block to local variable first. That's why  **first line** not complains error.

the local variable translationKeyBlock's value can be changed at any time before execute 
**_translateKey = translationKeyBlock;**

Maybe the reason is that compiler can't check translationKeyBlock's value when we're writing code.(I'm not sure 100%.)

I hope this can help you.